# Prove that there exist $W$ such that $V=V_1\oplus W=V_2\oplus W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are distinct linear subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim V_1=\dim V_2$, show that there exists a linear subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $V=V_1\oplus W=V_2\oplus W$

The following is what I had tried.

Let $\dim V_1=\dim V_2=a$ and $\dim V=b$
Since $V_1,V_2$ are subspaces of $V$ we have
$$a\leq b \implies b-a\geq 0$$

So I let $W$ be s subspace with dimension $b-a$
Hence,
$$\dim V_1+\dim W=\dim V_2+\dim W=a+(b-a)=a=\dim V$$

So here I conclude that $V=V_1\oplus W=V_2\oplus W$.

I do not know that my way of proving is correct or not. If not, please give me a complete idea about the proof. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that $$dim(V_1)+dim(V_2)=dim(V)$$ don't say that $V_1\oplus V_2=V$.

Comment: You need to show that there exists a subspace $W\subseteq V$ with $\dim(W)=b-a$ such that $W\cap V_1=\{0\}$ and $W\cap v_2=\{0\}$.

Comment: Another hint: look at $$U=V_1\cap V_2.$$ assume it have dimension $a-1$. Hence there is a vector $v_1\in V_1\V_2$ and a vector $v_2\in V_2\V_1$. Construct a new vector $w=v_1+v_2$. Then $$V_1\oplus span\{w\}=V_2\oplus span\{w\}.$$ I hope you can continue from here.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel Sorry I still do not have any idea. First what is the purpose to assume that it has dimension $a-1$? and also, how to relate it to $V$?

Comment: I don't think there is a reason to assume it's $a-1$. The point is in looking at the difference between $V_1$ and $V_2$. If they are the same, the rest is easy. If they are different, you can take a vector from each which is not in the other and their sum (call it $w_1$, for example) will not be in either of them. Then you repeat the process for $V_1\oplus span(w_1)$ and $V_2\oplus span (w_1)$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel for future reference: the MathJax for $V_1 \setminus V_2$ is `$V_1 \setminus V_2$`.

Comment: @ryagami Can you give me answer in detail? Because I can prove it by giving example but I do not have idea on proving it generally.

Comment: Here is a proof of a more general statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247773/find-common-complementary-subspace/3249038#3249038

Answer (score 0):

Assume dim$V_1$=dim$V_2$=r,dim$V$=n.

If  r=0 or r=n, it is trivial.

Considering $0<r<n$,firstly, because $V_1\cup V_2\ne V$, we find $\alpha_{r+1}\notin V_1\cup V_2$.

Now we consider $V_1$+span{$\alpha_{r+1}$}$\cup$$V_2$+span{$\alpha_{r+1}$}, so we can find $\alpha_{r+2}\notin$ $V_1$+span{$\alpha_{r+1}$}$\cup$$V_2$+span{$\alpha_{r+1}$}.

Repeating the above procedure ,we can get $\alpha_{r+1},\alpha_{r+2},\cdots,\alpha_{n}$.

Let $W$=span {$\alpha_{r+1},\alpha_{r+2},\cdots,\alpha_{n}$}.

So $V_1\cap W=V_2\cap W=0$ and dim$V_1$+dim$W$=dim$V_2$+dim$W$=n.

Thus $V=V_1\oplus W=V_2\oplus W$.