# Find subspace $N$ such that $M_k + N = \mathbb R^d$ for all $k$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Claim.** Let $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ be subspaces of $\mathbb R^d$. Then there exists a subspace $N$ with$$\dim N = d - \min_k\dim M_k$$such that $M_k + N = \mathbb R^d$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$.

In the case that the $M_k$'s all have the same dimension $d-1$, this is simple. One just has to pick a vector that is not contained in the union of the $M_k$'s (which exists since the union is of measure zero). Also if $\dim M_k = 1$ or all $k$, I can choose a vector $u$ which is not contained in the union of $M_k^\perp$. Then $u^\perp$ is complementary to each of the $M_k$'s as desired. But I cannot handle the general case...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I can answer the question myself:

Note that the union of finitely many *proper* subspaces of $\mathbb R^d$ cannot coincide with $\mathbb R^d$ because it has Lebesgue measure zero. Set $I_0 := \{1,\ldots,n\}$, $N_0 := \{0\}$, and proceed with the following algorithm (starting with $\ell = 1$):

$1_\ell$. Let $I_{\ell} := \{k\in I_{\ell-1} : M_k + N_{\ell- 1}\neq\mathbb R^d\}$. STOP if $I_\ell = \emptyset$.

$2_\ell$. Choose a vector $v_\ell\in\mathbb R^d\setminus\bigcup\{M_k + N_{\ell-1} : k\in I_\ell\}$ and set $N_\ell := N_{\ell-1}\oplus\operatorname{span}\{v_\ell\}$ for $k\in I_\ell$. Proceed with $1_{\ell+1}$.

When the algorithm stops with $\ell = r + 1$, we have found subspaces $N_0\subsetneq N_1\subsetneq N_2\subsetneq\ldots\subsetneq N_r$ with $\dim N_\ell = \ell$ for each $\ell$ such that for every $k\in I_0$ there exists $r_k$ such that $M_k\oplus N_{r_k} = \mathbb R^d$. Hence, $N_r$ is a subspace as desired.